# Project ARA electrical connectors

Tags: connector, smartphones

Looking at conventional smartphone flat flex cable connections, there looks to be a great deal more conducting pins/contacts than on these Project ARA models - Increasing the size of these connections looks great as I understand it could improve their durability, but how did ARA manage to *reduce the number* of contacts? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I understand that some of these images may be purely promotional, but I believe there are/ were working models out there.

[image: ARA concept connectors]

[image: typical connection]

[image: updated sprung connections?]

[image: Final connector type?]

[image: Final modules?]

Comment: Different connectors being used for entirely different purposes.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response - I'm new to this (mechanical engineer not electronics). I believe the type I showed is a board to board connector, used to connect daughter boards to the motherboard. E.g an iPhone will have a board to board connection between the motherboard and each camera. I assume project ARA has to do the same thing? How can the camera operate with so few lines?                                 I have a feeling I have completely misunderstood what the ARA connections are doing - could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: The connection between a webcam and a PC only needs four pins. It's more about what you do with the pins than how many you need.

Comment: Thanks again Finbarr. I'm working on a modular phone concept for my final year master's project at the University of Glasgow - how would you feel about a quick, informal chat about my concept and how this will affect my choice of connections? I'm struggling to find people who know what they're talking about and think even a 10 minute chat would help me out enormously.

Answer (score 2):

In the slots Project ARE phone used a custom 10Gb/s MIPI interface. You have power, presence pin and MIPI interface - four data lanes and one clock lane, and internal to the slot eject signal. For the data interface there was a custom Motorola bridge SoC.